# Need indentation for 'isov2' note and example classes?

Tags: indentation

Is there a better way to do this?

MVE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{isov2}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[toc,acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1
\parsep=0pt\topsep=0pt\partopsep=0pt}
\item[]}
{\endlist}
\newglossaryentry{accreditation}{name={accreditation},
    description={procedure by which an authoritative 
    body gives formal recognition that a body or person is
    competent to carry out specific tasks (ISO/IEC Guide 2)
    \begin{note} note one
    \begin{example}
      Should be indented!
    \end{example}
    \end{note}
    \begin{note} note two
    \begin{changemargin}{2ex}{0}
    \begin{anexample}
      Now indented!
    \end{anexample}
    \end{changemargin}
    \end{note}
    }
}
\newglossaryentry{latex}{name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents (Latexbook)
    \setcounter{note}{0}
    \begin{note} note one\end{note}
    \begin{note} note two\end{note}
    }
}
\newacronym{dc}{d.c.}{direct current}
\newacronym{ac}{a.c.}{alternating current}
\newacronym{DC}{DC}{direct current, d.c. is preferred}
\newacronym{AC}{AC}{alternating current, a.c. is preferred}
\begin{document}


\clause{Terms, definitions and abbreviations}
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\glsaddall
\sclause{Terms and definitions}
\printglossary
\sclause{Abbreviations}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\clause{Section}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. Your MWE basically worked for me. You might want to consider the `adjustwidth` envirinment from the `changepage` package instead of your `changemargin` but no matter. BTW the `isov2` class does not accept `oneside` or `12pt` options as when I wrote the class these were not allowed according to ISO's typographical rules; perhaps they have changed over the last 18 years.

Comment: @PeterWilson Thanks for you comments.  I will change accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd simply patch `example` and `anexample` to set a nonzero `\leftmargin`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{isov2}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[toc,acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\example}
  {\@setnoteparams}
  {\@setnoteparams\setlength{\leftmargin}{2em}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\anexample}
  {\@setnoteparams}
  {\@setnoteparams\setlength{\leftmargin}{2em}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{accreditation}{name={accreditation},
    description={procedure by which an authoritative 
    body gives formal recognition that a body or person is
    competent to carry out specific tasks (ISO/IEC Guide 2)
    \begin{note} note one
    \begin{example}
      Should be indented! \lipsum[1]
    \end{example}
    \end{note}
    \begin{note} note two
    \begin{anexample}
      Now indented!
    \end{anexample}
    \end{note}
    }
}
\newglossaryentry{latex}{name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents (Latexbook)
    \setcounter{note}{0}
    \begin{note} note one\end{note}
    \begin{note} note two\end{note}
    }
}
\newacronym{dc}{d.c.}{direct current}
\newacronym{ac}{a.c.}{alternating current}
\newacronym{DC}{DC}{direct current, d.c. is preferred}
\newacronym{AC}{AC}{alternating current, a.c. is preferred}

\begin{document}

\clause{Terms, definitions and abbreviations}
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\glsaddall
\sclause{Terms and definitions}
\printglossary
\sclause{Abbreviations}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\clause{Section}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If `example` should only be indented inside the `note` environment, you can patch it only inside `note`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{isov2}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[toc,acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\patchexamples}{%
  \patchcmd{\example}
    {\@setnoteparams}
    {\@setnoteparams\setlength{\leftmargin}{2em}}
    {}{}%
  \patchcmd{\anexample}
    {\@setnoteparams}
    {\@setnoteparams\setlength{\leftmargin}{2em}}
    {}{}%
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{note}{\patchexamples}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{accreditation}{name={accreditation},
    description={procedure by which an authoritative 
    body gives formal recognition that a body or person is
    competent to carry out specific tasks (ISO/IEC Guide 2)
    \begin{note} note one
    \begin{example}
      Should be indented! \lipsum[1]
    \end{example}
    \end{note}
    \begin{note} note two
    \begin{anexample}
      Now indented!
    \end{anexample}
    \end{note}
    }
}
\newglossaryentry{latex}{name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents (Latexbook)
    \setcounter{note}{0}
    \begin{note} note one\end{note}
    \begin{note} note two\end{note}
    }
}
\newacronym{dc}{d.c.}{direct current}
\newacronym{ac}{a.c.}{alternating current}
\newacronym{DC}{DC}{direct current, d.c. is preferred}
\newacronym{AC}{AC}{alternating current, a.c. is preferred}

\begin{document}

\clause{Terms, definitions and abbreviations}
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\glsaddall
\sclause{Terms and definitions}
\printglossary
\sclause{Abbreviations}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\clause{Section}

\begin{anexample}
text
\end{anexample}

\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Example only needs indentation inside the `{note}` environment.

Comment: @skvery You should better specify your question. New version online.